# Update another table using output of cte in teradata

Tags: teradata, common-table-expression

Technology: Teradata 16.20

I'm trying to update a table, that takes data from another table which uses CTE data.

I'm getting below error:

**Error:**

```
select failed 3707 syntax error, expected something like a 'SELECT' keyword or '(' or a 'TRANSACTIONTIME' keyword or a 'VALIDTIME' keyword between ')' and the 'UPDATE' keyword
```

**Question:**
Is it possible to update a table using another table that is getting joined with cte?

I know it can be done with a volatile table. I have seen CTE with insert statement and with select statement, but never seen cte with an update statement. Writing the same sql over and over for multiple self join only increases the lines of code. If this update can be done using CTE, that would be much easier and understandable

**Code:**

```
WITH NAME_CTE AS (
    SELECT FIRST.ID,FIRST.NAM,LAST.NAME
    FROM TABLE_FIRST FIRST INNER JOIN TABLE_LAST LAST
    ON FIRST.ID = LAST.ID
)
UPDATE SUBJECT_TEACHER_TABLE
FROM (
    SELECT CROSS_TBL.SUB_ID,
    COALESCE(CTE1.NAM,CTE1.NAME,CTE2.NAM,CTE2.NAME) AS FINAL_NAME
    FROM CROSS_REFERENCE_TABLE CROSS_TBL 
    LEFT JOIN NAME_CTE CTE1 ON CROSS_TBL.CR_ID1 = CTE.ID
    LEFT JOIN NAME_CTE CTE2 ON CROSS_TBL.CR_ID2 = CTE.ID
) PV
SET 
FINAL_NAME = PV.FINAL_NAME
WHERE SUBJECT_TEACHER_TABLE.SUB_ID = PV.SUB_ID;
```

**Modified Query: As per @dnoeth suggesstion**

```
UPDATE SUBJECT_TEACHER_TABLE
FROM (
    WITH NAME_CTE AS (
    SELECT FIRST.ID,FIRST.NAM,LAST.NAME
    FROM TABLE_FIRST FIRST INNER JOIN TABLE_LAST LAST
    ON FIRST.ID = LAST.ID)
    SELECT CROSS_TBL.SUB_ID,
    COALESCE(CTE1.NAM,CTE1.NAME,CTE2.NAM,CTE2.NAME) AS FINAL_NAME
    FROM CROSS_REFERENCE_TABLE CROSS_TBL 
    LEFT JOIN NAME_CTE CTE1 ON CROSS_TBL.CR_ID1 = CTE.ID
    LEFT JOIN NAME_CTE CTE2 ON CROSS_TBL.CR_ID2 = CTE.ID
) PV
SET 
FINAL_NAME = PV.FINAL_NAME
WHERE SUBJECT_TEACHER_TABLE.SUB_ID = PV.SUB_ID;
```

**Error:**

```
SQL Error [3807] [42S02]: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 15.10.00.22] [Error 3807] [SQLState 42S02] Object 'NAME_CTE' does not exist.
```

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: I know it can be done with a volatile table. I have seen CTE with insert statement and with select statement, but never seen cte with an update statement. Writing the same sql over and over for multiple self join only increases the lines of code. If this update can be done using CTE, that would be much easier and understandable.

Comment: You should not be adding information in comments; instead, [edit] your question and add them there, where they can be seen. And you've apparently not yet read the link I left for you.

Comment: Move the WITH CTE into the Derived Table

Comment: @dnoeth, moving CTE in the derived table throws error : SQL Error [3807] [42S02]: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 15.10.00.22] [Error 3807] [SQLState 42S02] Object 'NAME_CTE' does not exist.

Comment: @PawanVishwakarma - edit your question with the modified query.

Comment: @Andrew, Updated the question with the modified query.

Comment: You seem to run an older version of Teradata (at least the JDBC driver is 15.10), using CTEs in Derived Table was added in TD16. You could create view instead...